# log analysis for rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, monitoring, activeresource

i have a rails app which makes heavy use of activeresource and httparty to make api calls.

Is there any library/extension to log the requests and parse them, so that log analysis becomes easier and automated.

RailsLogAnalyser is good but what about extra calls, what are the conventions?

Something like a opensource/self-hosted alternative to newrelic, but with extensions to plug in your own logging.

EDIT: let me clarify:
1) if we use activereresource it logs the calls in a certain format but any plain-bones http calls u make will not follow this convention. 
2) a analytics/logging software that will make sense of the logs and have some metric of the number of calls made and count the number of calls etc.
3) will it support syslog, syslog-ng. Any other distributed logging framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have started playing around with [rails-analyzer](http://rails-analyzer.rubyforge.org/) but I am not sure if that will meet your needs or not. It seems to be aimed more at looking for optimization points but I have not delved enough to see what automated portions there are yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this, check this out maybe it will be helpfull for you this https://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer